# Как вывести информацию в виде плиток? JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx

Приложение берет данные с БД и должно выводить информацию в разрезе месяца в виде плиток (примерно так как в Google Keep [ссылка](http://viralmediatoday.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Google-keep-web.webp). Как это реализовать? Возможно можно создать какой-то шаблон в fxml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно создать метод который будет получать какие либо параметры (из БД) и возврощать тебе Pane 
Exmaple :

```
public VBox getBox(String param1, String param2 ...){
   VBox result = new VBox(10);
   result.setPrefWidth(200);
   result.setPrefHeight(200);
   result.setStyle(-fx-background-color:#FFFFFF);
   //Tyt loghika dobovlenya v VBox tvoih elementov + style na vash vkus;
}
```

В методе мэйн все это реальзуешь как то так

```
for(ResultSet elem : db.getDatabaseInfo(){
    root.getChilder.add(getBox(elem.getString(""), ....));
}
```